# Appending a number to a number?

Tags: c++

How cold I do the following:

say I have the number 10 and would like to append the number 317 to it. The resulting integer would be 10317. How can this be done. Also, once I have this number, how could I then for example remove the 17 off the end. Without using strings, and without obvious solving and adding.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by solving and adding?

Comment: Can someone explain the point of this question?  It smells of either homework or trivalness for the sake of trivialness, the latter of which is pretty localized/off-topic.  What's the practical reasoning behind wanting to do this?

Comment: @Argote I meant like, to add 10 to one you could figure out that you need to add 109

Comment: So you want to append the numbers whilst not treating them as numeric and not treating them as strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will append both numbers

```
int append_a_and_b_as_int(int a, int b)
{
    for(int tmp = b; tmp > 0; tmp % 10)
    {
        a *= 10;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

This will get rid of the last n numbers

```
int remove_n_numbers_from_a(int n, int a)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a /= 10;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Appending :

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a*pow(10, floor(log10(b))+1)+b;
}
```

Removing :

```
int bar(int a, int b)
{
    return a/pow(10, floor(log10(b))+1);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to cast those results back to `int`.

Comment: thats wrong, ceil(log10(b)) should be replaced with floor(log10(b))+1, I guess thats from the rush :)

Comment: @zvezdi Oh yeah, you're right. That's what I put at first, but then I thought that `floor(X) + 1 == ceil(X)`. It turns out it's not the case if X is already an integer. In my code then, there was a bug if `b` was an exact power of 10. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 317;
int result = a * 1000 + b;
```

For the second:

```
int result2 = result / 100;
```

Comment: He said "without obvious solving and adding".

Comment: I didn't realize that multiplying was called solving. :(

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you need to do in your workplace I'd advise quitting.

You can treat your two numbers as numeric data and solve the question, or you can treat them as strings and use an append.